# Is there any issues with having a separate ErrorProvider for each control?

Tags: .net, winforms, errorprovider

Normally you would have a single [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) for all the controls on a form; however I have a control that subtypes a textbox that need to show the user an error.   I don’t wish to have to put an error provider on every from it may be used on (more code changes then I would like)

So are there any issues in having each of my controls creating their own error provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues, I'd rather say a limiting use of the [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
since you won't be able to show errors for the controls that are not following the pattern.